# How to remove empty values in java like (,,,test,tester,,java_test,,,)

Tags: java

My String is like this: `(,,,test,tester,,java_test,,,)`. I need to remove the empty values from the list. Could you please share your thoughts for this?

Expected result: `(test,tester,java_test)`.

Comment: Is that "list" a String or a real `List`?

Comment: Sorry, the list is string (",,,test,tester,,java_test,,,")

Comment: Check every element in list via loop. Use isEmpty() built-in function in String class. If list is a string split string via split(",") method by comma character then check one by one.

Answer (score 2):

First remove double commas:

```
my_string = my_string.replaceAll("(,)+", ",");
```

Get rid of leading commas:

```
my_string = my_string.replaceAll("^,", "");
```

Get rid of trailing commas:

```
my_string = my_string.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

All together:

```
my_string = my_string.replaceAll("(,)+", ",").replaceAll("^,", "").replaceAll(",$", "")
```

In case the brackets make part of the string, the solution should be as follows:

```
my_string = my_string.replaceAll("(,)+", ",").replaceAll("^\\(,", "(").replaceAll(",\\)$", ")")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
list.removeIf(n -> (n == null || n.isEmpty()));
```

remove all the null elements and empty elements.

Comment: For `List<String>`, wouldn't you just be able to do `list.removeIf(n -> n.equals(""));`

Comment: you are right:-)

Comment: After your edit, you now remove everything from the list.  `n -> != null` means remove everything that is not `null`.

Comment: The OP has updated the post with more information and their "list" is actually a string

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add a little explanation. Why/how does this code work?